# sql query get Data on pre conditions

Tags: sql

i need fruit list which price greater than in tableA for each fruit.

```
ID   |  fruit | Price
----------------------------
   1 |  apple |   10  
   2 |  banana|   7  
   3 |  grapes|   6
```

then i have daily table like below

```
ID   |  fruit | Price
----------------------------
   1 |  apple |   9   
   2 |  banana|   5  
   3 |  grapes|   9  
   4 |  mango |   15
```

in this condition i get only grapes

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just join by `ID` and add your additional condition (`price` in `tableA` is greater than `price` in `dailyTable`).
you don't need to join by column `fruit` - but if so, it won't change your resultset.

```
SELECT TableA.*, dailyTable.Price
  FROM TableA
 INNER JOIN dailyTable
    ON TableA.ID = dailyTable.ID
   AND TableA.Price > dailyTable.Price
```

the column `fruit` is redundant data. so you shouldn't store it in the daily table.

Comment: This would yield apple and banana, not grape, which is what the OP mentioned as the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just join the `daily` and `tableA` tables on the fruit's `ID`, and then compare prices.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM daily t1
INNER JOIN tableA t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.price > t2.price
```

Note that we join on the `ID` rather than the fruit name, since in theory names may not be completely unique across a very large table of fruits.